# Rename Home screen icon

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, homescreen

is there a way for an app to rename its icon on the Home screen (Springboard)? The name comes from info.plist which is in the bundle; has anyone ever tried to change it in run-time, will it break anything?

Comment: duplicate of [Bundle Display Name in iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768472/bundle-display-name-in-iphone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it can't be done! You are not allowed to write to the application bundle, there's no other way to set the application name…

Comment: Note though that this is only true on unjailbroken devices.

Comment: @Freerunnering even this is not completely correct. I am able to modify the plist and other resources of applications that not belong to me (not jailbroken). [with PhoneDisk]. But after modifying an resource the iPhone will detect it and the App will crash directly on start. (wanted to replace an icon for retina because the developer stopped developing the App :D ) … btw this is how I unlocked all achievements in the Inception App ;)

Comment: @iPortable yes you can modify all AppStore apps jailbroken or not. But on jailbroken devices you can modify any file (except the binary) in the app bundle and still have the app working.